# ArcGIS Online: Display the "Last Updated" date of a layer through my web experience

Tags: arcgis-online

I have a map that uses three specific layers that are all programmatically updated on a set schedule and at the same time. How can I display the date that these updates occur in my web experience (the last modified/updated date from the layers)?

The data does not currently contain a date field, and I would like to avoid adding a date field to avoid schema changes and code modification - Ideally I would like to pull the date from the item details in AGOL.

Comment: Are you using one of the SDK's to build the web app? If not, I don't think there is any "out of the box" way to get a date from an item and display it.

Answer (score 0):

Using the ArcGIS API for Python, you can use the 'modified' property of an Item instance. Currently, it's not explicitly mentioned in the documentation for the Python API, but the Item page refers to the [docs for the REST API for an Item](https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/users-groups-and-items/item.htm).

And here's a [link](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/guide/experience-builder-workflows/) on using the Python API with a web experience.